# How can I search the flights of a specific airline given a date but no origin?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I am trying to avoid flying on Ryanair during a trip to Europe due to both the things I've heard as well as their very expensive check-in luggage costs. Wanting to fly to Morocco, pretty much the only reasonably cheap non-budget airline is Royal Air Maroc. I want to try and compile a list of their flights leaving from South-West Europe (Italy, Marseille, Nice, Spain etc.) because I can schedule my trip around the flight once I've booked it. I also am not too picky on which Moroccan city I land it, I just want to avoid landing past sundown because I hear it's not the wisest decision for solo travellers to hang around after that time, especially with all my luggage. So could anyone inform me on how to search for Royal Air Maroc flights departing on the 20th of December 2023 without having to manually test each city and destination to look for both good prices and good landing times. Thank you!

Comment: A word of warning: Luggage and set reservation fess for mainline carriers are often worse than that of budget carriers. Ryan Air is not the worst offender anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use Kiwi.

Example: https://www.kiwi.com/en/search/tiles/europe/morocco/2023-12-20/no-return?sortAggregateBy=price

[image]

The cheapest ticket is 19 USD (no check-in luggage included).

[image]

Limitation: can't filter landing time before selecting the route (but it can be done afterward).

Answer (score 4):

ITA Matrix is good for that type of thing. https://matrix.itasoftware.com/

Below is a one way search from Marseille or Nice to Marrakech or Casablanca on Dec 20.

The main restriction here is that all departure airports need to be in the same country, so you may have to do 3 different searches (France, Spain and Italy). You can restrict airlines and number of stops as well.

[image]